# - RESTCOMM Client API...over HTTPS/SSL

Tags: restcomm

Recently we have configured SSL to open WSS on our RESTCOMM server, as we got the issue of "getUserMedia()" deprecation issue because of insecure origin issue by chromium fix.
We managed to get WSS working and we can open RESTCOM Admin portal via HTTPs over 8443 port and even OLYMPUS is working too.
But because we have configured a SSL on RESTCOM Server i think even the REST Client API calls need to be on HTTPS too.  Am icorrect?

Becuase when we use the HTTP based URLs for programmatically adding clients by invoking REST Client APIs of RESTCOMM, then we are getting SSl certificate issues and the reason for this i think is that we have configured SSL cert to address the getUserMedia() security issue  by CHROMIUM fix.

can i request any solution or work around for this pls.

thanks in advance
ias

Comment: Yes, REST API is also behind HTTPS when this feature is enabled and should be considered by the programatically way that performs the access. But before adapt the automated way used to add new clients, could you try to test the REST API using cURL or similar to make sure everything is running well on Restcomm side? Here follows additional information about cURL with HTTPS/SSL: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#HTTPS_is_HTTP_secure